# How to change voice on windows VBS Script

Tags: windows, vbscript

So basically I'm making a program that talks whatever I programmed it to say, I'm making it in notepad on windows and it's a VBS script but I want to know if I can change the pitch of the voice or how it sounds in general? Here is the script:

```
Dim msg, sapi
Set sapi=creatobject("sapi.spvoice")
Sapi.speak"Hello world"
Lol=msgbox("Request done.")
```

Then i save it as .VBS in all files.

Comment: You read HELP to see what you can do. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723602(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Did you learn the generic lesson. Look in help for your options.

Comment: @ACatInLove I originally did I was just looking in the wrong section

Comment: Excellent glad to have pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, there is an error in your code.  Change `creatobject` to `createobject`.

And now, for the main code: ...

```
Dim msg, sapi
Set sapi = createObject("sapi.spvoice")
Set sapi.Voice = sapi.GetVoices.Item(1)
sapi.Speak "Hello world"
Lol = msgbox("Request done.")
```

Make sure to put this line `Set sapi.Voice = sapi.GetVoices.Item(1)` before the `sapi.Speak "..."`, otherwise the voice will still remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can always do it the easiest method which is just changing the default TTS voice. By going to speech recognition, and then text to speech.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Zira David

Zira's Voice
Set Zira = CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice")
Set Zira.Voice = Zira.GetVoices.Item(1)
Zira.Rate = 2
Zira.Volume = 70

Zira.Speak "My Name is Zira."
```

This another voice

```
Dim David

David's Voice
Set David = CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice")
Set David.Voice = David.GetVoices.Item(0)
David.Rate = 2
David.Volume = 100

David.Speak "My Name is David. It's nice to meet you!"
```

if you want to make your computer greet you when open the computer just choose any 1 from these two and open run box by pressing the winows button + R and type AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup and enter

Note: save these code in notepad then click on save as enter any name after the type .vbs then click on all files.all done